# Define a prototype for all types of variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I've written the following code in JavaScript

```
Object.prototype.is_string = function () {
 return typeof this === 'string' || this instanceof String;
}
```

This can be used for `String` values, `numbers`, `objects`, and `arrays`

But it cannot be used for `null` and `undefined` values.

How can this method be defined for all variable types?

Comment: Did you click that [`[Learn More]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/No_properties) link your browser was kind enough to give you? But note that your code will also miss Objects created from `Object.create(null);` and that modifying Object's proto like that will cost a lot. What's wrong with a simple function?

Comment: @Kaiido I know why this error occurred but I'm looking for a way to use the is_string for all types of variables

Comment: @Kaiido But it may be possible in another way

Comment: No.  `undefined` and `null` can not have any property. dot. In a non strict-mode scope, you could have a variable named `undefined`, for instance `var undefined = "bar"`, but that wouldn't change the value of the true `undefined` (as returned by `void 0`) and the fact this true `undefined` can't have a property. The only other way (which is probably the only correct btw), is to declare a function rather than modyfying the most used prototype in any js context: just declare an `isString = (val) => typeof val==="string"||val instanceof String;` function and use it like `isString(null)`

Comment: @Kaiido OK. Thank you for your guidance. I try to read more on this topic to better understand your explanations

Answer (score 0):

> In JavaScript, a primitive (primitive value, primitive data type) is data that is not an object and has no methods. There are 7 primitive data types: string, number, bigint, boolean, null, undefined, and symbol.

[Primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)

Basically, even though `typoef null` returns `object`, it is ***NOT*** an object but a primitive value. In your code, check for `null` values as well.

Answer (score 0):

`null` is not an object so it doesn't have any function to be executed on it.

Answer (score 0):

`null` and `undefined` in JavaScript are datatypes which do not have `prototypes` so they do not inherit their properties from `Object`.